# How to Vary for Traits for different devices without changing all. Using a stack view in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I'm creating a portrait interface with buttons.
I'm trying to use "Vary for Traits" after creating one screen to set the constraints so that the screen will work with other iOS screen sizes.
However, once I do this and open the different screen/device for a preview it's messing up the layout of the different device screen.
Is there a way I can just create one screen and have interface builder let me change the button positions, sizes and constraints so that I can compile for multiple screen sizes and devices?
If not is there code I can use to adjust the aspect ratio or screen size depending which device will be running the app?
Or do I need to create different screens for different devices and have code to recognise the device before opening the screen.
I was hoping to keep the project size as low as possible so was trying to avoid having too many different assets in the project.
Sorry for being long winded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's quite frustrating.

Comment: Basically no, no, no, no, and no. Size classes make the distinctions that they make, and that distinction is only very roughly related to device type. Regular/regular means this is an iPad. Compact/regular means this is an iPhone in portrait (or an iPad doing multitasking). And so on. If you've designed your interface properly, that should be all you need to know.

Comment: Thanks Matt. for some reason, even with constraints added for the stack view taking into account safe view, when I preview the other devices all the sizes and spacing is messed up. I'm only compiling for iPhone devices in portrait and this is really causing problems. I thought all I'd have to do was create each page and make sure the constraints were within the screen sizes but it seems I can't compile for iPhone X without messing up the layout on iPhone 6 and vice versa.  I've tried making the stack view the full screen size but no joy. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok but from here I have no idea what is in your stack view, what its settings are, or what its constraints are. You can’t just say things are “messed up” and expect to get help.